# Solving system of ODEs using different methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So here I have my system of ODEs with its initial conditions:

$y_{0}''+1=0$

$y_{1}''+y_{0}'+2y_{0}'y_{1}'=0$

$y_{2}''+2y_{1}'^2=0$

The initial conditions are $y_{0}(0)=1$ and $y_{1}(0)=y_{2}(0)=0$ along with $y_{0}'(0)=1$ and $y_{1}'(0)=y_{2}'(0)=1$

If you can give me a hint as to the method then I might be able to figure it out on my own but its been a while since I took ODEs.

Comment: Is this related to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1247625/115115 ? Have you decided on which differential equation you are trying to solve, $y''+ϵ(y')^2+1=0$ or $y''+ϵy'+1=0$? At the moment, your equations are related to neither.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve the first equation with $$y_0''+1=0$$ with the solution
$$y_0(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1+C_2x$$